# How to sort an integer array into negative, zero, positive part without changing relative position?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-partitioning

Give an O(n) algorithm which takes as input an array S, then divides S into three sets:  negatives, zeros, and positives. Show how to implement this in place, that is, without allocating new memory. And you have to keep the number's relative sequence. 
for example:
{-1, 4, 0, -2, 1, 2} ==> {-1, -2, 0, 4, 1, 2}

I am not sure whether or not such an solution exits. The best solutions I can think out are:

Solution 1: Using an extra integer array, then traverse the whole array to get negatives, then 0s, then positives.

Solution 2: Do not keep number's relative sequence. Then loop the array two times:

```
    template <typename Type>  
void Partion(Type *array, int begin, int end, Type v, int &l, int &r) 
{  
    l = begin;  
    for (int i=begin; i!=end; ++i)  
    {  
        if (array[i] < v)  
            swap(array[i], array[l++]);  
    }  
    r = l;  
    for (int j=l; j!=end; ++j)  
    {  
        if (array[j] == v)  
            swap(array[j], array[r++]);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: what about three loops, one for each set, doing a bubble swap each time a member of the set is encountered?

Comment: Are you partitioning the array into three sets (negative, zero, positive) while keeping relative positions of numbers in each set intact? I'm asking because your example seems contradictory - `{-1, 4, 0, -2, 1, 2} ==> {-1, -2, 0, 1, 2, 4}`. If items are truly sorted, then -2 appears before -1, and if they are grouped as `(-,0,+)` while keeping the relative positions of numbers in each group intact, then the result should be `{-1, -2, 0, 4, 1, 2}` where 4 appears before 1 and 2.

Comment: @Anurag thank you for your notification. I fixed it.

Comment: @mmr, I think your algorithm is not O(n), since you have to move elements a lot times, and moving the element might be O(n) itself.

Comment: Even though your comparison criterion is looser than is typical, it seems to me that this is still a comparison-based sorting, so the O(N log N) lower limit probably still applies.

Comment: @Gin-- no, it's still only three passes through.  start with the negative set, sweep through, keep an index to the first element to swap.  So start at element 0 for your swap index.  Have another index sweep through.  Once it hits a negative, swap with the first index, increment the first index, continue until you get to the end.  Repeat for zeros.  Positives should be done at that point.

Comment: @nmr what if the example had been {-1, 4, 1, -2, 2, 0}?  The algorithm you describe would leave {-1, -2, 1, 4, 2, 0} after the first pass.  Note that the 1 and 4 have been reversed.

Comment: The only stable sort algorithm with linear time complexity that I know of is teh Counting Sort, but you have to know the range of the numbers.

Comment: +1 for a problem that has generated a lot of interesting response.

Comment: @AShelly-- O(N) does not mean 'single pass'-- it means that it can't go to O(N log N).  Double or triple passes are still O(N), just with a different constant than a single pass.

Comment: @mmr, my point wasn't about the number of passes, it was that the sequences are not preserved with simple swapping.  ex: `{1 -2 0 2 0 3 -1}`; pass1 => `{-2 -1 0 2 0 3 1}`; pass2 => `{-2 -1 0 0 2 3 1}`.  If you change to a 'bubble swap', you are back to N lg N.

Comment: Is it valid to assume that maintaining "relative sequence" does not matter for the set of zero values?  What would it matter if they were swapped?  0 == 0 == 0.

Comment: @AShelly-- good point.  Guess I'm not going to solve what others are saying is the DNF in a few comments :)

Answer (score 16):

This is an instance of the [Dutch national flag problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) studied by Edsger Dijkstra.  It's interesting in that no **stable** solution to this problem is known that runs in O(n) time and O(1) space (or at least, the last time I checked the literature, no known solution to the problem exists).

Comment: An O(n) time and O(n) space solution is straightforward.

Comment: @James McNellis- True, but the OP asked how to do this in-place (I assume that means O(1) memory)

Comment: Yep; that would be my assumption.

Comment: I don't think this is quite the Dutch national flag problem. In that problem, no element can be moved more than once and the elements of each class are indistinguishable (there is no stability requirement). The present problem allows elements to be moved up to O(1) times but the elements must be partitioned in a stable way.

Comment: This is a variant of the DNF problem for stable ternary partitioning. You're correct that it's not a perfect fit, but my claim that this hasn't yet been solved still holds. Thanks for pointing that out,

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this helps, but the requirement to stably partition into three classes can be reduced to the problem of stably partitioning into two classes: separate the negative from non-negative, then the positive from non-positive. If the two-class problem can be solved in O(1) space and O(n) time, the solution can be applied twice to solve the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Zeros are indistinguishable so I presume you don't care whether they get swapped around or even simply overwritten at the end (i.e. we just zero out the middle part after we've finished getting the positive and negative numbers moved to opposite ends of the array).

If you're looking at a situation where the integers are just keys for something bigger, this may well not be the case- you may want zeros preserved and stably partitioned. But if not, here's two insights:

First, your problem is identical to the stable binary partition problem.

An algorithm for your problem of course does stable binary partitions (just an array with no zeros). Contrariwise, if the array has zeros you can still use a binary partition to do the dirty work:  scan right through the array, swapping each zero you come across with the next negative value (keeping track of where that was so you don't do n^2 overall scanning), resulting in

[mixed -,+][possibly extra zeros][mixed 0,+].

Then you do two binary partitions to get

[-][+][0][+]

and shift the + values over to get the desired result.

AFAIK with binary partitions you can choose any two of stable, in-place, and O(n). So it looks like you're outta luck, but apparently an in-place O(n*log n) algorithm is known as is an O(n) algorithm using log(n) scratch space.

Second, if you can guarantee that the number of zeros will be at least f(n), the zeros can compensate for the lack of scratch space; it's simple to get a stable in-place partition in time O(n^2/f(n)). In particular, if the zeros will be at least some constant fraction of the array, you get O(n) runtime by just running these two steps till you're done:

1. Scan right through the array, swapping each zero you come across with the next negative value
2. Scan left through the array, swapping each zero you come across with the next positive value

If zeros are just as plentiful as either of the other types, this is done after doing 1 then 2 then 1 again.

Comment: can you please extend this answer with references to back up your statements?

Answer (score 0):

Can't this be done simply using any "stable sort" performed with a custom comparitor which only checks the sign?

Edit:
*No, that's O(n log n).*

One thing you can do in linear time is reduce the problem.  Since the zeros can't be ordered (how do you tell one from the other?), you can make a pass where you walk through the array, skipping the zeroes and filling in with the non-zero values.  Then add the correct number of zeros at the end.

```
j=0;
for (i=0;i<N;i++) {
  if (A[i]) {
     A[j++]=A[i];
  }
}
while (j<N) {
   A[j++]=0;
}
```

Now you can ignore the last section and the problem becomes finding an O(n) algorithm for a stable partition around 0.   Unfortunately, the `stable_partition` function [from the c++ stl](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stable_partition.html) has only O(n) comparisons, but O(n log n) swaps if no additional space is available.

However, this article: ["Stable minimum space partitioning in linear time"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.25.5554&rep=rep1&type=pdf) seems to indicate that it is possible in O(n). I don't think I understand it well enough to summarize it clearly here.

If that works, The final step is to insert the zeros back inbetween the partitions, which is also O(n), since the zeros have no order to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ library has a [`stable_partition`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stable_partition.html) algorithm which requires *n* comparisons and O(*n* log *n*) swaps when it runs in-place.

As @Ted [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347616/how-to-sort-an-integer-array-into-negative-zero-positive-part-without-changing/5349371#5349371), the problem requires two applications of this algorithm.